# Select From Database when related user id is used in other rows

Tags: mysql, select

I want to create a tree through registered members through other members

| ID | user | user2 | side | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | right | 22-11-2023 01:00:00 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 | right | 23-11-2023 01:00:00 |
| 3 | 3 | 4 | left | 24-11-2023 01:00:00 |
| 4 | 4 | 5 | right | 25-11-2023 01:00:00 |
| 5 | 5 | 6 | right | 26-11-2023 01:00:00 |
| 6 | 10 | 8 | right | 26-11-2023 01:00:00 |

### so how to get results when user = 1 then fetch ID from 1 to 5

output ID : 1,2,3,4,5
Can you help me find an idea to complete this ?

Comment: There is an idea, Select Where user2 in each row equals user. Is this possible?

Comment: Add the expected output in the question, may be an image

Comment: output ID : 1,2,3,4,5

Comment: provide the output for `SELECT @@version;`

Comment: I don't know if it will work : `WITH RECURSIVE UserLinks AS ( SELECT ID, user, user2, side, date FROM YOURTABLE WHERE user = 1 UNION ALL SELECT t.ID, t.user, t.user2, t.side, t.date FROM YOURTABLE t INNER JOIN UserLinks ul ON t.user = ul.user2 ) SELECT ID FROM UserLinks;
`

Comment: Try giving other  `user = 2` and see if working as expected?

Comment: work like a charm u should post it as answer with this small edit (WITH RECURSIVE UserLinks AS ( SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE user = 10 UNION ALL SELECT t.* FROM yourtable t INNER JOIN UserLinks ul ON t.user = ul.user2 ) SELECT * FROM UserLinks)